# Visual Studio 2022 current line of Code jumps to next line when debugging Application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

Hi I having been facing this issue since I upgraded from Visual Studio 2019 to 2022. In the debug mode when using the F10 or F11 the current code line being debugged jumps position to the Next / previous line randomly.

For example the original lines of code was

```
        If intTotWidth Mod Val(txtRollWidth.Text) <> 0 And pgState = "I" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Total of Cut Rolls Width of " & intTotWidth / Val(txtNoOfRounds.Text) & " does not Match Roll Width of " & txtRollOriginalWidth.Text & ", cannot save.", "Error in Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtCutWidth.Select()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

after running the application with the debug the code now shows like so

```
        MessageBox.Show("Total of Cut Rolls Width of " & intTotWidth / Val(txtNoOfRounds.Text) & " does not Match Roll Width of " & txtRollOriginalWidth.Text & ", cannot save.", "Error in Save", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        If intTotWidth Mod Val(txtRollWidth.Text) <> 0 And pgState = "I" Then
            txtCutWidth.Select()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Can someone pls help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that while debugging, the order of your code is re-written?  Does it reset again afterwards?  And probably nowhere near any sort of answer, but general feedback.  Val() is very obsolete now and for good reason.  Suggest you do some reading on Integer.Parse() and Integer.TryParse().  And bonus reading Short-circuit comparisons _AndAlso_ over conventional _And_

Comment: Yes the order is re-written of the line that is being debugged, either it may move a line up or a line down. And no, it does not reset again afterwards. Also, thanks for your feedback

Comment: That’s a rather bizarre issue you’ve got going on there, could even guess why.  Maybe do a screen capture video and post on the visual studio feedback site and go more direct to the source